# What is the average radius of the hypercube?

Tags: geometry

How do I compute the average radius of an hypercube from its center  as a function of the dimensionality of the space? (averaging over directions from the center)

Here I consider the hypercube defined as $C_n=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: -\frac{1}{2}\leq x_i\leq\frac{1}{2}, \forall_{i\leq n}\}$ with center $(0, ..., 0)\in\mathbb{R}^n $

I have found the formula $\sqrt{\frac{n}{2\pi e}}$ but this does work for the square ($n=2$) So I guess it must be wrong.

I suspect there is no closed form solution. If this is indeed the case, I would also appreciate a numerical efficient method to compute it

Comment: How do you define "radius" in this context?

Comment: @AymanHourieh distance from the boundary of the cube to the origin

Comment: Is this the average radius averaging over directions from the center or averaging over points on the hypercube?

Comment: @DarkMalthorp I edited my question

Answer (score 3):

If a better answer becomes available, consider this a long comment.

The formula $\sqrt{\frac{n}{2\pi e}}$ is a large-$n$ asymptotic approximation.

Promote each coordinate $x_i$ to a random variable $X_i$. Let $D$ denote the distance to the hypersurface, so $D^2=\frac14\sum_iY_i^2$ with $Y_i:=2|X_i|\sim U(0,\,1)$. The MGF of $Z:=4D^2$ is obtained [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-Distribution-of-Sum-of-Squares-of-Uniform-Random-Variables); your problem is to compute $\frac12\Bbb EZ^{1/2}$. But I don't think you can do much better than the above approximation & Monte Carlo for a specific $n$.

Comment: Why do you think you can't get an exact answer? There are two distinct interpretations of the question as per Dark Malthorps comment but for either one you can write down an explicit $n$-dimensional integral that gives you the average.

Comment: @quarague Because slide 10 [here](http://ssa.cf.ac.uk/pepelyshev/pepelyshev_cube.pdf) only gives the asymptotic result. Anyway, integrals like that are easier said than done.

Answer (score 2):

For $n=2$ it is sufficient to average  only over $0\leq\phi\leq{\pi\over4}$. I then get
$$r_{\rm average}={4\over\pi}\int_0^{\pi/4}{1\over2\cos\phi}\>d\phi={1\over\pi}\log\bigl(3+2\sqrt{2}\bigr)\approx0.5611\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity I will consider the cube $[-1,1]^n$, which is twice the size of the cube in your question. It is sufficient to find the average radius for one face, say $x_1=1,x_2\in[-1,1],\dots,x_n\in[-1,1]$. A patch of surface area $\mathrm dx_2\cdots\mathrm dx_n$ at $(1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ is at distance $(1+x_2^2+\dots+x_n^2)^{1/2}$ from the center, and subtends solid angle $\mathrm dx_2\cdots\mathrm dx_n/(1+x_2^2+\dots+x_n^2)^{n/2}$. Therefore the average radius of the double-size cube is
$$\frac{\int_{-1}^1\cdots\int_{-1}^1(1+x_2^2+\dots+x_n^2)^{-(n-1)/2}\,\mathrm dx_2\cdots\mathrm dx_n}{\int_{-1}^1\cdots\int_{-1}^1(1+x_2^2+\dots+x_n^2)^{-n/2}\,\mathrm dx_2\cdots\mathrm dx_n}.$$

For $n=2$, this gives $\frac4\pi\log(1+\sqrt2)\approx 1.1222$, which is twice the value in Christian Blatter's answer as expected. For $n=3$, Mathematica does not evaluate a closed form, but numerically it is approximately $1.22137$.